# Trying to understand Typescript generics

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm have the following function:

```
interface ExtraModels extends Model {
  unknown: string
}

const write = async (data: ExtraModels[]) => {
  console.log(data[0].unknown)
}
```

Which is working. Now I want to change with:

```
const write = async <T = ExtraModels>(data: T[]) => {
  console.log(data[0].unknown)
}
```

But it doesn't compile with the error:

Property 'unknown' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)

I don't understand what I'm doing it wrong here. From what I've studied this is valid.

Comment: use `<T extends ExtraModels>`

Answer (score 3):

It is valid but it does not do what you expect it to. `= ExtraModels` means `T` will be `ExtraModels` if it is not possible to infer `T` from arguments. But `T` can be any type, including one that does not extend `ExtraModels` (this is why the compiler doesn't let you access properties of `ExtraModels`)

You want to constrain `T` to be a type that extends `ExtraModels`. The syntax for that is `T extends ExtraModels`. Since `T` must extend `ExtraModels` typescript will let you access properties of `ExtraModels`.

```
const write = async <T extends  ExtraModels>(data: T[]) => {
  console.log(data[0].unknown)
}
```

Comment: Oh I see! I was understanding this in the wrong way. thank you, it's working now :D.